# Transition Rate as a function of time

Tags: r, traminer

I've spent a while discovering `R` and the `TraMineR` package to be able to analyse a MySQL export of the transition events (states for the purpose of this discussion) of my DB items (so in `TSE` format).

I have 10 states, which can transition to any other state (ie there is no specific order).

I've managed so far to convert this data to `STS`, using a basic time unit of 1 hour, to be able to use the `seqtrate` function, which provides me the absolute transition rate from each state to each other state (in a 10x10 table).

What I'm having trouble with is to calculate the transition rate as a function of time. I was imagining this would be displayed as a 10x10 table again, but instead of absolute values in each cell, it might be a discrete graph, representing the rate according to different times (e.g <24h, 24-72h, 72-168h, >168h).

There is the `time.varying` option for `seqtrate`, but it calculates the rate for every time unit, and I don't see an option to define specific timeframes.

I also thought of using `SPS` but I couldn't find any specific functions to do this.

Is there another function for me to be able to do this? Or would I need to code this manually using `seqtrate`'s `time.varying` option? If it's the latter, could you put me on the right track, I'm not sure where to start.

UPDATE (just an example to clarify what I would like to get for the first 3 states)

```
        |               State1                  |               State2                  |               State3                  |
State1  | av(<24),av(24-72),av(72-168),av(168+) | av(<24),av(24-72),av(72-168),av(168+) | av(<24),av(24-72),av(72-168),av(168+) |
State2  | av(<24),av(24-72),av(72-168),av(168+) | av(<24),av(24-72),av(72-168),av(168+) | av(<24),av(24-72),av(72-168),av(168+) |
State3  | av(<24),av(24-72),av(72-168),av(168+) | av(<24),av(24-72),av(72-168),av(168+) | av(<24),av(24-72),av(72-168),av(168+) |
```

Comment: If you want your transition rates to vary with time, they will be different at each time point. So, I cannot figure out how you would represent that with a single 10x10 matrix. Please clarify what you want to do with a minimal example of say 3 states and 3-4 time points.

Comment: @Gilbert I've added a visual example above to clarify what I mean, does that make more sense?

Comment: @Gilbert, I've also realised that creating a seqdef from sts makes the time absolute, while i would need to calculate the average as relative to the start of each task, not average from the time start of the  entire data set

Comment: From your example, it appears that you want an element for each time interval in each cell, i.e., a transition probability for each time interval. Please let us know if the answer below is what you expect.

Comment: By the way, the way data are organized (STS, SPS, ...) will not change anything. Internally, `TraMineR` transforms any non STS state sequence format into STS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you would like to get transition probabilities over age classes (time intervals since the start of some process.), while your data are aligned on a calendar time. i.e., time of occurrence rather than time since start of the process.

So, you need first to change the alignment of your sequences. The `TraMineRextras` package offers the `seqstart` function for that. Here is an example where we transform panel data into age aligned data.

```
library(TraMineRextras)
## Example data aligned on calendar years, starting in 2000
paneldata <- matrix(
    c("A" , "A" , "B" , "A" , "A" ,
      "A" , "A" , "B" , "B" , "B" ,
      "A" , "A" , "B" , "B" , "B" ,
      "B" , "A" , "A" , "B" , "B" ,
      "A" , "B" , "A" , "A" , "B"), byrow=TRUE, ncol=5)
colnames(paneldata) <- 2000:2004

## original sequences aligned on years 
(s.panel <- seqdef(paneldata))  

## Sequence         
## 1 A-A-B-A-A
## 2 A-A-B-B-B  
## 3 A-A-B-B-B    
## 4 B-A-A-B-B      
## 5 A-A-A-A-B

## Change from calendar date to age alignment
startyear <- 2000
birthyear <- 1995:1999 ## just to illustrate
agedata <- seqstart(paneldata, data.start=startyear, new.start=birthyear)
colnames(agedata) <- 1:ncol(agedata)

## sequences aligned on ages
(s.age <- seqdef(agedata))  

## Sequence         
## 1 *-*-*-*-A-A-B-A-A
## 2 *-*-*-A-A-B-B-B  
## 3 *-*-A-A-B-B-B    
## 4 *-B-A-A-B-B      
## 5 A-A-A-A-B
```

Once you have aligned your sequences correctly, you simply compute transition probabilities on intervals of times, here age classes 1-5 and 6-9.

```
seqtrate(s.age[,1:5])

##        [-> A]    [-> B]
## [A ->] 0.6363636 0.3636364
## [B ->] 0.3333333 0.6666667

seqtrate(s.age[,6:9])

##          [-> A] [-> B]
## [A ->]   0.50   0.50
## [B ->]   0.25   0.75
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Gilbert! This seems like what I need. Though I'm having a bit of troube getting the `new.start` vector for  `seqstart`. Does `TraMineR` or `TraMineRextras` have a function to extract the first date for each sequence which isn't the default (`None` for me)?

Comment: @Victor.dMdB The `data.start` is a choice of the user. As in my example, it generally is the time stamp of the first element in the sequence, i.e., the time associated to the first column in the STS form. To set it as the first occurrence time of say state B, you could consider the `seqfpos` `TraMineR` function. For example, you get the position of the first valid state of `s.age` by proceeding as follows: `s.TF <- seqdef(s.age=="*")`;
`first.valid <- seqfpos(s.TF,"FALSE")`.